# SPS/ TwinCat/ Syntax Error-Code/ Declaration of TON and TOF

Tags: twincat, structured-text

I am currently programming in ST (TwinCat), but two errors occured, which I do not understand at all. 
Error-Code says:
(1) (TRUE AND TON_01.Q) is no valid assignment target
(2) Q is no input of TOF

I already declared Q as my Output , but TON and TOF cannot handle it. The Code and the Error is attached to the post. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TqEg.png)

Thank you for your Help.

Comment: Show code examples.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing an assignment of `TOF_01.Q` and not a check.
So instead of:

`IF TOF_01.Q := TRUE ...` it should be

`IF TOF_01.Q = TRUE ...` or simply

`IF TOF_01.Q...`

Same with TON_01.Q obviously.